# .htaccess wildcard subdomain apontando para directory + hash

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewrite, subdomínio, wildcard

Bem simples a dúvida.
Redirecionamento por .htaccess contendo um subdomain wildcard e hash.

De:

```
http://carros.domain.com/visualizar#123
http://casas.domain.com/visualizar#345
http://aps.domain.com/visualizar#567
```

Para:

```
http://domain.com/carros/ver#123
http://domain.com/casas/ver#345
http://domain.com/aps/ver#567
```

Meu maior problema é trocar o "visualizar" para o "ver".
Tentei inúmeras formas e falhei na missão.

Algo aproximado que achei por aqui no stack:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com/visualizar
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/%1/ver/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

EDIT:

Solução que funcionou baseada nas respostas dessas pessoas lindas:

```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} carros\.domain\.com
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} visualizar([^#]+)?([#\d\w\s]+)?
   RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/ver%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

Repeti isso para todas os meus subdominios.

Comment: Então mostre o que tentou.

Comment: Adicionei o exemplo que estou trabalhando encima

Comment: Podes explicar melhor se isso tem de funcionar com vários dominios ou se partes como "domain.com", "carros" são fixas?

Comment: Não, o dominio é fixo. Já o "carros" é wildcard. Dei uma melhorada nos exemplos. Veja se fui claro.

Answer (score 2):

Essa regra redireciona todos os subdomínios:

```
   RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.foo\.bar$
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.foo.bar/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Com base nisso, o seu caso ficaria assim

```
   RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.foo\.bar/visualizar$
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.foo.bar/carros/ver$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Trabalhei encima do seu exemplo, não consegui. Dei uma melhorada no meu exemplo. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Usando a possibilidade da regex ter grupos de captura numerados acho que isto pode funcionar:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^https?:\/\/([^\.]+)\.domain\.com\/([^#]+)([#\d]+)$ http://domain.com/$1/ver$3 [R=301,L]
```

Baseado no comportamento da regex assim: https://regex101.com/r/qG3vO5/1, a ideia é capturar 3 grupos e reagrupar 2 deles no rewrite.

Comment: Olha, não sabia que dava pra usar direto na Rule. Usei seu exemplo e deixei os grupos de captura como opcional.  Bom, testei em localhost mas sem sucesso:  `RewriteRule ^https?:\/\/([^\.]+)\.localhost\/([^#]+)?([#\d]+)?$ http://localhost/$1 [R=301,L]`