# Configuração do htaccess para subdomínio coringa

Tags: htaccess, redirecionamento, subdomínio

por gentileza, tenho uma entrada coringa no meu domínio,  ou seja, qualquerNome.meudomino.com.br redireciona para meudomino.com.br. Preciso configurar o meu htaccess para redirecionar todas entradas parar um arquivo, no qual, conforme o subdomínio, redireciono adequadamente. Como ficaria este arquivo htaccess, considerando que o arquivo que vai avaliar este subdomínio vai receber da seguinte forma: arquivo.php?domain=Xxx. Onde XXX é o subdomínio requisitado.
Fiz a segunite regra abaixo, que funciona a princípio, porém, não consigo padronizar o comportamento da regra quando é requisitado com o "www" e sem o "www".

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.dominio\.com\.br
RewriteRule (.*) http://dominio.com.br/domain.php?id=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Muito obrigado por antecipação.

Comment: Possível solução em [.htaccess wildcard subdomain apontando para directory + hash](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103318/htaccess-wildcard-subdomain-apontando-para-directory-hash)

Comment: Olá @Bacco, editei a pergunta, pois ainda tenho o problema do "www". que quando utilizado ou não possui efeitos diferentes